# SDL2: Render engine design

Tags: c++, oop, draw, sdl-2

I am creating simple game rendering engine based on SDL2 library. My design looks similar to this ASCII graph.

```
DrawTarget     RenderTarget
    |                |
    |                |
    +---> Window <---+
```

`DrawTarget` is an abstract class for draw target suitable to SDL_Surface blitting.
`RenderTarget` is and abstract class for render target suitable to SDL_Texture.
`Window` is derivated class managing SDL_Window, SDL_Renderer and all draw and rendering functions.

```
Renderable
  |  |  |
  |  |  |
  |  |  +-> Player
  |  |         ^
  |  |         |
  |  +----> Animation
  |            ^
  |            |
  +-------> Texture
```

`Renderable` is everything, which could be rendered to the screen or another RenderTarget.
`Texture` is SDL_Texture implementation. Texture should not know its own position.
`Animation` has a private Texture member allowing set up of animation frames. Animation itself should not known the render position.
`Player` has a private Animation member. Player should know the current position.

In this time, I have one `SDL_Renderer` per window and pass it all around Textures, Animations etc. Texture is with knowledge of `SDL_Renderer` render itself to the screen. But I do not think calling Texture->draw( x, y ) all the time is efficient and cache friendly.

I like the way SFML renders. All renderable object have `draw` method, which just calls the window's draw method. I would like to implement similar system.

This will break my requirement some Renderable objects know their render position, some do not.

For example class Player should not have `render( x, y )` method, because it knows its position. On the other hand, Texture class should not have `render( void )` method, because it does not its position.

My ask is following: How to design SDL2 suitable render engine with as little overhead as possible?

Comment: I think your question is too broad, what specific problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: You can either have objects draw themselves, or a renderer draw objects. I'd advise the latter based on experience. You can store weak pointers to drawable objects in a container and have the renderer loop through it when needed.

Comment: @paulm I would like to create universal rendering engine which should be able to render both objects with position ( Player ) or objects without position (Texture, Animation).

Comment: @OMGtechy Yes, rendering through renderer/window is the way I will choose.

Answer (score 5):

Answering your question of: "My ask is following: How to design SDL2 suitable render engine with as little overhead as possible?"

A quick explanation of a scalable, lazy renderer scheme for minimizing SDL2 renderer overhead:

A "layer" consists of all the textures that have the same z attribute.
Layers are marked as invalid whenever a texture in that layer is modified. 
Layers are managed when the renderer runs, which is at a set framerate. 
The max layer and the highest invalid layer are kept track of. The renderer 
starts at the highest invalid layer and ends at the max layer. Each layer is
set as the renderer target and cleared. The previous layer is then copied to
the current layer. Then it iterates through each texture in the layer, 
redrawing those marked invalid, and copies each texture on top of the current 
layer. The result is that the previous layer is the background while the 
current layer drawn on top of it. This texture is cached and invalidated when 
the layer is marked invalid. After running through any invalid layers, set the
render target back to default (null), copy the highest texture to the screen, 
and present.

In a 2d with layers user interface type of environment, the above is 
scalable and lazy. On my low end Celeron n2830 my test applications idle at
0% cpu usage. It more or less stayed that way even when I added a hundred
test layers. Since it only draws from what layer changed upwards, and all
changes are enqueued at a reasonable framerate, very little work actually
ends up being done. Iterating through the invalid layer to the max layer appears
asymptotically friendlier then iterating through all layers every run. Running
the renderer at a set interval and doing all the drawing then helps to save time
because it will ignore excess changes that wouldn't have been seen anyways. 
It's been worth it to use some application code to avoid having to draw
stuff and copy textures. Those tend to take longer then a few if checks and 
attribute lookups.

note that this design was intended for 2d with layers, like a user interface.
some principles may not neccessarily work well in other environments.

Also the above only supports textures and not surfaces. Mixing the two
was for me not worth the complexity. Getting the sdl2 renderer to draw to a 
particular texture took some figuring out, but serves my needs well enough 
alone. If you mix the two it appears difficult to avoid some additional work.
Plus textures benefit from a gpu, which adds to efficiency wins in terms of 
cpu time.

In my system, window objects have a draw method. This method enqueues draw
operations with the renderer instead of drawing them immediately. Window
objects have an area attribute. To support objects that do not have an area 
attribute, maybe you could apply a wrapper that does around your object that 
does not. That way when prompted for an area it can still provide one, even 
though it doesn't have one internally. Or maybe use a table that maps
your object to an area, or a method call of whatever object does track its
texture. I'm not sure of the nature of that limitation.

Note that this draw method is a hybrid approach of objects drawing themselves and
the renderer drawing objects. The objects appear to draw themselves, while the
renderer actually does the work.

In short:

- textures are signficantly faster then surfaces
- enqueue draw and copy operations for batch processing
- cache textures when they are drawn
- cache layers after copying all textures to them
- use the caches to avoid rendering all but the invalid layers to max layer

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me what you are saying is that you want entities to only know their position, but for rendering you want it to be completely separate. Every entity will need to store some kind of rendering data. I would say you should look at a component based entity system. There are different classes for position, renderdata, input etc. Try [Component Based Entity System](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/understanding-component-entity-systems-r3013)

Comment: I do not know I like this way of creating objects. It needs a lot of overhead - checking whenever the object has needed component or has not, reaction based on used component etc. Tell me if I am wrong.
On the other hand, I problably will use this for for game Entities ( NPC, Player, ... ).

Comment: @Lorin Well yes i meant entities. Either every entity could have the same components, or you could have an array with a certain amount of components. Each component could maybe have an id? Overall I'm thinking you could SAVE memory like this. Then you could give each entity a pointer to an AI object or something.